# Change text on mouse over

Tags: php, jquery

I need to change the text to the mouse hover over the buttons
i try this code but doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($){
    $(".cat-item-13").hover(function () {
     $('#text-digital-solution p').hide().html("<?php echo term_description('13','casestudies_category'); ?>").fadeIn('fast');

    });
 });
</script>
```

this is error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Can you use the snippet editor to create a real example with HTML? For example what is the content of `term_description('13','casestudies_category');` - if it contains a double quote the statement will fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a safer version. I assume you are failing due to quotes or newlines in the text from PHP

The encoding is taken from [Pass a PHP string to a JavaScript variable (and escape newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines) - which, if it solves your issue should result in your question being marked as duplicate

```
$(function(){
  var desc = decodeURIComponent("<?php echo rawurlencode(term_description('13','casestudies_category')); ?>");
  $(".cat-item-13").hover(function () {
    $('#text-digital-solution p').hide().html(desc).fadeIn('fast');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me if it works:

```
var test = '<?php echo term_description("13","casestudies_category"); ?>';
 $(".cat-item-13").hover(function () {
     $('#text-digital-solution p').html(test).fadeIn('fast');
    });
```

I am not sure to be honest if the PHP will be putout correctly, beacuse PHP commands are getting done on pageload.

Comment: Will STILL fail if the php text contains single quotes

Comment: yeah you are right, i will correct it... it was a long day today^^

Comment: i try this solution, but doesn't work.
where i fail?

<script type="text/javascript">

    var  mytext = '<?php echo term_description('13','casestudies_category'); ?>';
  $(".cat-item-13").hover(function () {
     $('#text-digital-solution p').text(mytext).fadeIn('fast');
    });

</script>